# devise skip authentication based on route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Having devise_for :users makes all methods of Users controller authenticated by Devise. I'd like to skip a couple of methods e.g `users#api, users#do_stuff` for making a public API with self-written auth method.

How can I do it?

UPDATE.

```
skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:api, :do_stuff]
```

still gives me `{"error":"You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."}`

Comment: try with `before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:apiv1, :do_stuff]`.

Comment: why: ...only: [:api`v1`, :do_stuff] and not ...only: [`:api`, :do_stuff]

Comment: can you please post the controller

Comment: GRIPE ALERT: I guess this is one of the problems with rails - the answer would be self-evident if we were allowed to combine routing with responses directly like a roda routing tree. then the answer would be self-evident, instead we must rely on `skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:api]`and needlessly complicate our routing logic.

Answer (score 9):

Try this -

```
skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:api,:do_stuff]
```

Comment: Still gives me {"error":"You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."}

Answer (score 1):

inside `users_controller.rb`...add the below lines

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, :only => [:api, :do_stuff]
```

i assume that you only want to authenticate on this two method calls in users_controller and not have added any authentication filter in application_controller.

Comment: use except block instead of only to authenticate only the required methods and add skip_before_filter :authenticate_user! to application controller to skip authentication for all except to the one used in expect block.

Comment: Any reasons why would I do that?

Comment: you can either authenticate ALL and skip FEW or SKIP all and authenticate FEW.

Comment: I'd like to skip authentication only on api and do_stuff. I thought using only is a way to do it. Am I wrong?